# Redirect to a Plugin Settings Page After Multisite Site Creation?

Tags: multisite

I am using a geo-tag map plugin called Geo Mashup, along with a WordPress Multisite install.

When I create a new site, an alert appears (in the admin alerts area) immediately telling me I have to go to the settings page to update the database:

> "Geo Mashup needs to upgrade its database, visit the settings to do it now."

And simply visiting this page (`Settings > Geo Mashup`) on the new 'sub site' makes it work.

Is it possible to redirect the browser to the new site plugin's setting page right after creating the new site?

Comment: Hi, did you ever figure out a good way to do this? If so, it would be great to post your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The following code does the redirect. In this example, the redirection is to a BackupBuddy's page.

```
add_filter('admin_head-site-new.php','wpse_35760_redirect_after_site_creation');

function wpse_35760_redirect_after_site_creation()
{
    if( !isset($_GET['update']) || 'added' != $_GET['update'] )
        return;

    switch_to_blog($_GET['id']);
    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'admin.php?page=pb_backupbuddy_multisite_export' ) ); 
    exit;
}
```

For reference: [Related Answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71023/12615) that uses an Action Hook fired on blog creation.
But, for the case in this Question -redirect after creation-, I think the approach used here may be better.