# WordPress (+WPMU) Import/Export ALL settings?

Tags: multisite, import, options, export

As we all know WordPress does not import Widgets when you import content with [Tools > Import] and I'm wondering what kind of script could do that? Database has more than just 1 single information related to sidebars unfortunately.

Another question would be - how to auto-import XML file without WordPress Importer? I'm looking for auto-import solution when someone setups new WPMU website. I'd like settings, posts, pages, comments, sidebars etc. to import as soon as user sets up new WPMU website. Perhaps there are already ready solutions that I'm not aware of so any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Answering [another Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/75377/12615), I pointed to this tutorial:

> [Creating a Simple Backup/Restore Settings Feature](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/creating-a-simple-backuprestore-settings-feature/)
>   `Lee Pham on Jun 22nd 2012`
>   In this tutorial, I’m going to show you how to create a simple backup/restore feature for your WordPress blog. With this feature, you can backup all options to another place, that you can restore them from at any time without configuring them again.

All Widgets options are stored in `wp_options` table.
So, the plugin developed in the tutorial will deal exactly with the information not handled by WordPress Exporter/Importer, i.e., restore all Widgets and all other site options.

I haven't tested the plugin as it is intended nor in a MS environment. I used it to create a plugin import/export options page.

If you want to run something just after a site creation, check this Q&A: [Redirect to a Plugin Settings Page After Multisite Site Creation?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35760/12615)

IMO, the second Question, *"How to Auto-Import a XML?"*, deserves [another Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

**[update]**
It is possible to modify the default content for new sites *(Hello World, Uncategorized, Sample Page, Blogroll)* using this technique: [Populate content on install](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/75420/12615)

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to read all that soon :) Thanks!